# Compiling python program on HTML page

Tags: javascript, python, html, ubuntu-14.04

I need to create a website using HTML & CSS which can take input data from user, pushes the data to some python program, gets compile in python and prints the generated output back on the website. I do not have much experience in JavaScript or creating website in any python framework.
How can I possibly compile python code on web server if I have designed the page in HTML & CSS or I have to make the website also in python framework?

Comment: We are not here to do your work, at least show an **attempt** at your code?

Comment: You're describing a web application, go and do some research on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are frameworks. You should look at django.

AWS run instance servers if you need to host, but other providers are available. (You can run a server from your own PC if you must).